# Pytorch RNN with no nonlinearity

Tags: python, pytorch, filtering, recurrent-neural-network

Is it possible to implement an RNN layer with no nonlinearity in Pytorch like in Keras where one can set the activation to linear? By removing the nonlinearlity, I want to implement a first-order infinite-impulse-response (IIR) filter with a differentiable parameter and integrate it into my model for end-to-end learning. I can obviously implement the filter in Pytorch but I thought using an inbuilt function may be more efficient.

Comment: If you want to remove the activation and make the RNN linear, it's the same as using a `nn.linear` with no activation set, since the time-distributed component complete gets removed. Check my answer for more details.

Comment: You interpretation of an RNN without nonlinearity as linear transformations is technically correct but not practical. It doesn't make sense to me to unfold, say, 250 recursions to turn them into a set of 250 linear transforms with growing dimensions.

Comment: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/customize-an-activation-function/1652/10

Comment: The "for" loops in python are excruciatingly slow. The main sequence loops of the RNN models of Pytorch are implemented in C: [link](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py#L15).

Comment: @Reza, I am not talking about 250 linear transformations but 1 linear transformation over the input vector sequence.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think so, you can choose between tanh and relu but is to be one of them when using `nn.RNN` as far as I know (and I dont think there is a work around). But you could implement the RNN youself quite easily without using the implemented module and then use whatever activation you want. They show an example of that in [this](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/char_rnn_classification_tutorial.html) Pytorch tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

**Removing non-linearity from RNN turns it into a linear dense layer without any activation.**

If that is what you want, then simply use `nn.linear` and set activation to `None`

#### Explanation

Here is why this happens. Fundamentally, an RNN for timesteps works as below -

[image]

```
h(t) = tanh(U.x(t) + W.h(t−1) + b)

h(0) = tanh(U0.x(0) + b0)
h(1) = tanh(U1.x(1) + W1.h(0) + b1)
h(2) = tanh(U2.x(2) + W2.h(1) + b2)

#... and so on.
```

If you remove linearity by removing the `tanh`, here is what happens -

```
h(0) = U0.x(0) + b0
h(1) = U1.x(1) + W1.h(0) + b1
     = U1.x(1) + W1.(U0.x(0) + b0) + b1 #expanding x(0)
     = U1.x(1) + W1.U0.x(0) + W1.b0 + b1
     = U1.x(1) + W1.U0.x(0) + W1.b0 + b1
     = V1.x(1) + V0.x(0) + C    #Can be rewritten with new weights
     = V . x + C    #General form
```

So the final form of the state of an RNN after 2 timesteps is simply `Wx+b` like the linear layer without activation.

In other words, removing the non-linearity from an RNN turns it into a linear dense layer without any activation, completely removing the notion of time-steps.

Comment: V1.x(1) + V0.x(0) + C shows 2 time-steps. These do not disappear in the General form. So the statement "completely removing the notion of time-steps" is incorrect.

So, by removing the non-linearity, you end up with a multidimensional linear layer, across both width and time dimensions.

Finally, at each step the time dimension of V has to increase.
Theoretically, you thus obtain a linear recurrent system (like an IIR filter).
Practically, because the batch has finite sequence length, V is a fixed size matrix (thus like a FIR filter). Though, still with a time-steps dimension!

Answer (score 1):

No, the PyTorch [`nn.RNN`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.RNN.html) module takes only Tanh or RELU:

> **nonlinearity** – The non-linearity to use. Can be either `'tanh'` or `'relu'`. Default: `'tanh'`

You could [implement this yourself](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/customize-an-activation-function/1652/10) however by writing your own for loop over the sequence, as in [this example](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/time_sequence_prediction/train.py#L11).